# How connect ec2 kafka brocker from localhost

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am unable to connect kafka brocker from my local machine, my kafka and zookeeper running on ec2 instance,
we have allow the ufw & inbound rules i can able to access other ports execept my kakfa port, i have done telnet and my ip 9092 not no luck.

I have tried with docker also.

Here is my server.property, please help me what I have done wrong here.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-ip.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://ip-ip.ap-south-1.compute.internal:19092,EXTERNAL://ip:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL

OR

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://PUBLIC_IP:9092
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally we resolved this issue by changing the network, my organization block the network due to this issue we are unable to connect, if anyone having similer issue, please change your network.